# Interpretation of Rabi frequency and generalised Rabi frequency

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, oscillators, perturbation-theory

In quantum mechanics, what is the difference, in a two level system, of the processes described by the [Rabi frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_frequency) defined as $$\Omega := \frac{\langle 1| e \vec{r} \cdot \vec{E_0}| 2 \rangle}{\hbar}$$ and the [generalized Rabi frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_frequency#Generalized_Rabi_frequency) given by $$\omega_r := \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(\omega - \omega_0)^2 + \bigg(\frac{|V_{ab}|}{\hbar}\bigg)^2}?$$

Answer (score 0):

The presence of $\omega$ in the second expression should give the game away: what you call the 'generalized' Rabi frequency is the frequency of the oscillations in population when you drive a two-level system *off*-resonance, i.e. at some frequency $\omega$ which does not quite match the resonance frequency $\omega_0$. At resonance, when $\omega=\omega_0,$ it is easy to see that this reduces to
$$
\omega_r = \frac{1}{2} \frac{|V_{ab}|}{\hbar},
$$
which is exactly the same as your initial expression for $\Omega$ when you account for the different conventions and normalizations in use.

Comment: Okay. As an example, given electric field $\vec{E} =E_0 \cos(\omega t)\hat{k}$, would I be correct in stating that the Rabi frequency is $$\Omega = \frac{\langle1| e \vec{r} \cdot \vec{E_0}|2 \rangle}{\hbar} = \frac{e \langle1|z|2 \rangle|E_0|}{\hbar},$$ where $\vec{E_0} = |E_0|\hat{k}?$

Comment: No. That result only holds at resonance, i.e. if $\hbar\omega$ exactly matches the difference $\hbar\omega_0$ between the ground and excited-state energies.

Comment: This is what they define as Rabi frequency in [Atomic Physics by Foot](https://www.amazon.de/Atomic-Physics-Oxford-Master-Optical/dp/0198506961) page 124.

Comment: *sigh*. You can define whatever you want as whatever you want. However, if you drive off-resonance, then the Rabi frequency so defined will not match the frequency of the oscillations in population; this may or may not be OK with you. This is all conventions and terminology so it is entirely irrelevant to the physics.